# Django Rest Framework using Extra Actions to make foreign key data routable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, action

I have two models which are each in a different app. Stock model references Financials model through a foreignkey relationship as shown below. with the current Stock Viewset, also displayed below, I am able to access the individual stock through localhost:8000/stocks/aapl, but I would like to extend that url to include the financials foreign key data such as localhost:8000/stocks/aapl/financials/balance-sheet/. I was told to use Extra Actions, which I've attmpted and posted below but no luck.

Any clue how to do this ?

```
class Stock(models.Model):

    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True)
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(default="", editable=False)
    financials = models.OneToOneField(
        Financials, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None
    )

    def get_financials(self):
        return self.financials
```

financial model

```
class Financials(models.Model):

    # ticker = models.ForeignKey(
    # Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="balance_sheets"
    # )

    balance_sheet = models.ForeignKey(
        BalanceSheet, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="balance_sheets"
    )

    income_statement = models.ForeignKey(
        IncomeStatement, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="income_statements"
    )

    cashflows_statement = models.ForeignKey(
        CashflowsStatement,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="cashflows_statements",
        default=None,
    )
```

stocks.views.py

```
class StockViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Stock.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StockSerializer
    lookup_url_kwarg = "ticker"
    lookup_field = "ticker__iexact"

    @action(detail=True, methods=['post', 'get'])
    def financials(self, request, ticker=None):
        stock = self.get_object()
        financials = stock.get_financials()
        return Response({financials})
```

Comment: as per your current config, the new extra action can be retrieved by accessing the URL: `localhost:8000/stocks/aapl/financials/`

Comment: so the configuration is correct and should return the financials ?  there is a problem somewhere else then

Comment: what was the result then? got error? I didn't find any such details in your OP

Comment: you have to serialize data before sending it in response. So make financials serializer and return. eg. `return Response(FinancialSerializer(data=financials).data)`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu there wasn't an error, it just returned financials with null

Comment: does `financials` has any value? @AranFreel